# Menu settings item for web browser android

Tags: android, android-menu, android-browser

I am having an application requirement where on use of any browser, a new settings menu item has to be created. For that, we need to add some functionality. First of all, please guide if this is possible at all in the first place. If so, please guide how to achieve the same.